# How to resolve dart error --Exception has occurred. _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: dart

I am getting the following error in Dart..

Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String')

This is my code,,

```
class Hits {
 String incentives;
 Hits({
   this.incentives,
 });

Hits.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   incentives = json['incentives'];
}

}
```

The value in the JSON has 1 of the following value

```
0:"incentives" -> List (1 item)
   key:"incentives"
   value:List (1 item)
   [0]:""
   String:""
```

OR

```
0:"incentives" -> null
key:"incentives"
value:null
```

Can you give me a hit on how to resolve this error..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code provided here describes the problem precisely.

The `json` map has a property named `"incentives"` which is a list (`List<dynamic>`) with one element.
You try to assign this value to the field `incentives` which has type `String`.

Since a `List<dynamic>` is not assignable to `String`, that fails.

It fails at runtime because the *static* type of `json['incentives']` is `dynamic`, so the compiler cannot determine at compile-time that the value is not assignable to `String`. As the type error states: "type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String'".

I'm not sure how to *solve* the problem, because it's not clear which value you actually want to assign to `incentives`. Maybe all you need is to change the type of the `incentives` field to `List<dynamic>`. That depends on how the class will be used.